# Why is the css style not applying to the modal?

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui

For some reason the css style is not applying to the React Modal. Any reason why?

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Modal defaultOpen={this.props.isShowing} className="openmodal">
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
}
```

CSS File

```
.openmodal{
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like? Any clues there?

Comment: where is .openmodal code placed? inside a .css file or directly below the render function like in the code you provided?

Comment: Could be because Modal doesn't take className as an attribute. Share more of the code so we can figure it out.

Comment: @DavidNeto the .openmodal is inside a css file.

Comment: @Erik it says it does http://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/modal

Comment: Use your browser inspector to see if the class is applied by React. If it is, your issue is with including the CSS.

Comment: Yeah so I made the width important which fixed the width, but for some reason it does not show because of no height, but the position is a relative so the height should appear right?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a javascript style you apply it like this;

```js
const openmodal = {
  content: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    borderRadius: '0',
    width: '400px',
    position: 'relative'
  }
}

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Modal defaultOpen={this.props.isShowing} style={openmodal}>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Try with the inline style.

Comment: I have the .openmodal in an external css file. I have updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: My edited answer was for react-modal. I don't know how semantic-ui modal works.

Answer (score 0):

It should be portalClassName:

```
<Modal defaultOpen={this.props.isShowing} portalClassName="openmodal">
</Modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

It comes with its own DOM structure and its own set of classes.

[image]

so you have to target those classes in the screenshot